# Unwrap function parameters / each parameter for new line

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I dont know how to use this option and i can't find it in docs (accidentally clicked keys on keyboard).
This is not reformat code (CTRL+ALT+L)

Before:

```
var a = [];
a.push({id: 0, test: 5});
```

I want:

```
var a = [];
a.push({
  id: 0, 
  test: 5
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Most likely you just reformatted you code ... (`Code | Reformat`)

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl+Alt+L` ?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/reformatting-source-code.html?origin=old_help

Comment: You're all wrong, this option reformat file, not selected line.  @RayonDabre Yes, this is not it.

Comment: Did you ever mention that you are trying to format selected line ? Correct your question before pointing finger over others :(

Comment: @RayonDabre sorry for that, i think that should be clear with "inline" word in title. Corrected title.

Comment: @exexe *"You're all wrong, this option reformat file, not selected line."* OK ... Did you know that if you make a selection .. then this command will reformat **selection only**?

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, i know that, but this command do nothing in my code. Reformatting whole file by this command gives same result.

Comment: @exexe **Now** it's clear that this was not "Reformat" action. On another hand -- with my settings it reformats 1st code (one liner) into 2nd one (4 lines) here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> JavaScript -> Wrapping and Braces -> Set Object literals to "Chop down if long"**